# How to filter a query in an alphabetical order (SQLAlchemy, Flask)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

For example:

```
@app.route('/courselist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def courselist():
  courses = models.Course.query.all()
  return render_template('courselist.html', title = 'Manage courses', courses = courses)
```

Is there any way to order this query alphabetically?

EDIT : Those are my models

```
class Course(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
  courseCode = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
  duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
  maxStudents = db.Column(db.Integer)
  startDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  prerequisites = db.Column(db.String(500))
  trainerID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('trainer.id'))
  venueID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venue.id'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear how your *SQLAlchemy* is configured, but based on what you show, I think you can do it like:

```
@app.route('/courselist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def courselist():
  courses = models.Course.query.order_by(models.Course.name).all()
  return render_template('courselist.html', title = 'Manage courses', courses = courses)
```

So here you add the `.order_by(..)` part and you order on the `Course.name` (so the name of the `Course`). You can of course order on another column by modifying the `.order_by(..)` part.